# Is it possible to use a bare pointer in a similar way to Unique pointers?

Tags: c++

So I'm currently undertaking a task where a unique pointer would be ideal but I was told to transfer the ownership using a bare pointer and wondering if this is possible? I had a crack at it below but unsure if it's the correct implementation.

```
int *p1 = new int(3);
int *p2 = new int;
p2 = p1;

std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
std::cout << p2 << std::endl; //Memory address same as above

delete p1;
p1 = nullptr;

std::cout << p1 << std::endl; //Now returns 0
std::cout << p2 << std::endl; //Same address as above

delete p2;
```

Comment: This code is wrong because `p2` points at the same place as `p1` and therefore `delete p2;` is double-deletion.

Comment: `p2 = p1;` throws away the value that was assigned to `p2` in the preceding line. That's a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

```
  int* p1 = new int;
  int* p2 = new int;

           +------+
  p1   --> |      |
           +------+

           +------+
  p1   --> |      |
           +------+

  p2 = p1;

           +------+
  p1   --> |      |
  p2   --> |      |
           +------+

           +------+
           |      |  memory leaked
           +------+

  delete p1;
           
  p1   now pointing to an invalid address
  p2   now pointing to an invalid address
  p1 = nullptr; //     p1 is now null;
  delete p2; // undefined behavior
```

In order to do what you want you need make sure you keep track of ownership your self. E.g.

```
int* p1 = new int;
int* p2 = p1; // you need to keep a reference counter somewhere
```

there are many ways to do this e.g. you could overload the new operator and add a reference count to a list of memory blocks.

Comment: A canonical solution already exists in C++, it is `unique_ptr`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DanNestor yes, OP explicitly asked for an alternative way - see title to question. It is always preferred to use what is there but sometimes one does things to learn.

Comment: The question asks only if it's possible to transfer ownership with raw pointers. Perhaps adding to your answer some info about unique_ptr and why that is preferred might help.

Comment: It sounds as if he already knows about unique_ptrs and that he has an assignment to use raw pointers, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Use `unique_ptr` to represent and transfer ownership.

Ownership refers to the fact that a certain memory region is "owned" by a pointer variable, which is a way of expressing that the memory pointed to by that variable is in use. That means the memory should not be released until all the owners have ceased to exist (and of course, it would be nice if that would happen automatically).

Ownership is not built into the language in C++, which means you cannot express ownership by using some special C++ syntax. In your code example, for example, this leads to problems like the double deletion others have pointed out. Nothing prevents you from doing `delete p2` since there is no expression of ownership.

You need to rely on defining your own type to express ownership and ensure code correctness when doing operations such as ownership transfer. You could write your own solution, but this is exactly what smart pointers do, and if you don't have a special reason, you should prefer using them. Of these, `unique_ptr` is the appropriate choice if you want a unique owner, that is, a certain object that is owned by only one owner at a time (though you can transfer that ownership to a new owner).

Here are some useful guidelines:

- [A raw pointer (a `T *`) is non-owning](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-ptr)
- [Use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to express ownership](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-owner)
- [Take a `unique_ptr<widget>` parameter to express that a function assumes ownership of a `widget`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-uniqueptrparam)